# How do I generate inferences locally from a model fit in Sagemaker?

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I built a custom container on Sagemaker to allow me to tune a Catboost model.

I then fit the model with the best hyperparameters (as if I were to deploy on Sagemaker).

I downloaded the tar.gz file onto my machine.

I can read the file:

```
import tarfile

file = tarfile.open('model.tar.gz')
```

I can extract from the file:

```
file.extractall('./output')
```

I now have a file named `catboost_model.dump`, but I am unsure where to go from here.

Is it possible load in this `.dump` file to generate inferences?

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to load your model artifact into Catboost, using [load_model()](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboost_load_model) (probably). or you can use the SageMaker Python SDK to run an inference endpoint [locally](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#local-mode). You need to have Docker installed to do this